# Get all columns exposed by views in a database

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 database that is used for transferring data, in this database we have 30-40 views.

I need to report all the columns that are exposed by these views.

Is there a way to query all the views in the db and output those columns?

Thanks

Comment: why a downvote? Some people just love downvoting for the sake of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT 
    [schema] = s.name, 
    [view]   = v.name,
    [column] = c.name
  FROM sys.views AS v
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON v.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON v.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
  ORDER BY [schema],[view],c.column_id;
```